# F# int64 to int

Tags: f#, type-conversion

How can I convert an `Int64` to an `Int32` type in F# without using the `Microsoft.FSharp.Compatibility.Int32.of_int64`?

I'm doing this because interactive doesn't seem to work when I try:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Compatibility
```

With `FSharp.PowerPack` added as a reference it says:

> error FS0039: The namespace 'Compatibility' is not defined.

**Edit:** Does anyone have an answer to the question?  The suggestions about the int types are useful and informative, but I'm having the same issue opening the powerpack namespace in F# interactive.

Answer (score 23):

F# 1.9.6 has a type conversion function so you can do this:

```
let num = 1000
let num64 = int64(num)
```

Answer (score 11):

Notice that in this type of conversion, when you reduce the size of a value, the most significant bytes are thrown away, so your data might be truncated:

```
> let bignum =  4294967297L;;
val bignum : int64

> let myint = int32(bignum);;
val myint : int32

> myint;;
val it : int32 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the functions for converting to each integer type have the same names as the types themselves, and are defined in the library spec (see below).  (With the release of the CTP (1.9.6.2), a lot of the library and the namespaces changed a bit compared to previous releases, but it will probably be more 'stable' moving forward.)

http://research.microsoft.com/fsharp/manual/FSharp.Core/Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.html